# Can I know: what the algorithm of encryption used in p12 certificate?

Tags: encryption, certificate, rsa

I have old p12 certificate. Can I know what encrypted algorithm used: RSA-1024 or RSA-2048?

Answer (score 1):

PKCS#12 is not a certificate and the key size is not an algorithm. The key within the X5.09 certificate in the PKCS#12 has a public modulus though, and the size of the modulus is equal to the key size. If you use an online decoder, don't give it the entire PKCS#12 key store as it probably includes your private key.

Comment: Sorry, not quite understand you. Is that impossible to know the size of the key?

Comment: No, just retrieve the certificate from the PKCS#12 key store. Then get the modulus/key size. You can also temp. import it into your Windows certificate store and check its properties, the key size should be one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it using one of the cert decoders online such as https://certlogik.com/decoder/

Comment: But how I get this string from my p12 file?